# Stored Procedure SQL Server management, los formatos de fecha no me cargan

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Estoy realizando un backup con un stored procedure, el formato de fecha que me hace este codigo es el 02 yymmdd, y necesito que sea con el formato 126 YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM: SS.mmm, pero al momento de modificarlo me sale el siguiente error.

> Cannot open backup device 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\BikeStores2_2022-03-18T10:15:38.220.bak'. Operating system error 123(El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos.).
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure backup1, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 13]
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Dejo el codigo que estoy usando aqui abajo, alguien me podria ayudar a solucionar este problema?

```
    go
create procedure backup1
as
declare @fecha varchar(max)
declare @archivo varchar(max)
set @fecha = CONVERT(Varchar(max),GETDATE(),02)
set @archivo = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\BikeStores2_'+@fecha+'.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE BikeStores TO DISK = @archivo
WITH FORMAT,
NAME='BikeStores';
```

Comment: El archivo `BikeStores2_2022-03-18T10:15:38.220.bak` existe?

Comment: Ese archivo no existe, no me lo genera el codigo, quiero que justo se genere, con la solucion que me brindaron se genera de la misma forma solo con yymmdd, y lo que yo requiero es que sea con YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM: SS.mmm

Comment: Asi es, el formato debe de ser con el nombre de la base de datos de la siguiente forma
DbName_YYYYMMDDhhmm

Comment: Lo he probado y now() provoca lo siguiente
'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: si,todo esto es en sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que los nombres de archivos no pueden llevar dos puntos (:). Necesitarías quitarlos para que el nombre del archivo sea válido.
El siguiente código puede generar algo cercano a lo que deseas removiendo los 2 puntos.

```
declare @fecha varchar(max);
declare @archivo varchar(max);
set @fecha = REPLACE( CONVERT(Varchar(max),GETDATE(),126), ':', '');
set @archivo = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\BikeStores2_'+@fecha+'.bak';

BACKUP DATABASE BikeStores TO DISK = @archivo
WITH FORMAT,
NAME='BikeStores';
```

Como ejemplo, el nombre quedaría algo así

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\BikeStores2_2022-03-18T132117.420.bak
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! 
Fue la solución, si quedo justo como me dijiste 
Que bonita comunidad

Comment: Que podria hacer para que no incluya los segundos al momento que me genera el backup, unicamente hh mm?

Comment: Cambia el MAX por un 16 en la asignación del valor a @fecha.